# Problem finding page element in Salesforce Lightning for user script

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I don't understand why this is happening and I can't seem to find the answer.

I'm trying to write a userscript for Tampermonkey in javascript that will add a couple of dropdown lists to a Salesforce Lightning page, under an `input` element that has "Type a topic name and press Enter." as *placeholder*. My problem is that whereas I can inspect the element in the browser and find it in the page, I cannot find it with the script and I don't understand why.

Inspecting the page elements in the browser, this is the input's definition:

```html
<input lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" id="input-219" type="text" role="textbox"
autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type a topic name and press Enter." aria-autocomplete="list"
class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" aria-controls="dropdown-element-219">
```

But when I ran this code as a snipet in Chrome to test it,

```js
var tinputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var ti;
for (ti = 0; ti < tinputs.length; ti++) {
    if (tinputs[ti].placeholder == "Type a topic name and press Enter.") {
        alert(tinputs[ti].id);
    }
}
```

I got no alert at all.

Then I tried the following code to get the list of the placeholder of all the inputs, to see what comes up,

```js
var tinputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var ti;
for (ti = 0; ti < tinputs.length; ti++) {
    console.log(ti,'->',tinputs[ti].placeholder);
}
```

And in the Console I get 30 or so,

> <value of ti, increasing> "->" ""

For some reason it can't pull the placeholders of the inputs and can't tell why. Any idea why this may be happening? Btw, similar outcome I get if I log `tinputs[ti].id` instead of the *placeholder*, and also if I use `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` instead of *querySelectorAll*.

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: If you give an example page, then I can check it.

Comment: Thanks, @erosman! That's kinda tricky because this is the first time I try to do this, and come across this problem, and it's in the Salesforce ticketing system, not something really "public". I understand it's a difficult question to answer, I just don't know how to better present it or what more information can I provide.

Comment: Can you create a sample page for testing?

Comment: You figure this out?